# Passing $Data Of Cgridview Row To other View File in yii

Tags: yii

How can I pass $Data of cgridview row to other view file? I have Cgridview in my view.php file and the following code.
cgridview code

```
<?php 
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
'id'=>'siteaccess-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$siteaccess->search(),
'filter'=>$siteaccess,
'columns'=>array(
    array('name'=>'ownerID', 'header'=>'Site Owner'),
    array('name'=>'siteID', 'header'=>'Site ID'),
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 10px'),
        'template'=>'{dashboard}',
        'buttons'=>array (
            'dashboard' => array (
                'label' => 'Open Dashboard',            
                'options' => array(
                    'data-toggle' => 'modal', 
                    'data-target' => '#myModal',
                ), 
                'icon' => 'briefcase',
                'csrf'=>true
            ),
        ),  
    ),
    ),
)
); 
?>
```

This is Tabs code which I am displaying in modal window. When I click on each row of cgridview it launches modal window in which tabs are displayed and I render _graph in one of the tabs. Thus I want to pass clicked row $data to _graph.

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'type'=>'pills',
    'tabs'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Dash1', 'id'=>'dash1',  'items'=> array(
            array('label'=>'Sub Dash1', 'id'=>'subdash1', 'content'=> $this->renderPartial('_graph', true, true)),
```

Now I want pass the selected row $data in cgridview to _graph.php file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below, not tested but you should get the idea.

```
 'content'=> $this->renderPartial('_graph',array('data'=>$data->id))),
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because $data variable can only be used inside cgridview and for only 'url' and 'visible' .

Comment: Can you post more of the view file, including the gridview and if possible the controller action that render this view?

Comment: Hmm, basically you would need to pass the $data to the modal and then pass it on to the renderPartial.